# Function with loop only returns last value

Tags: php

I need to assign a variable to be the output of a function that contains a loop.

Current function:

```
function dateRange($numberofDays){
    while($x<=$numberofDays) {
        $currentNumber = "-" . $x . " days";
        $date = DATE('Y-m-d', STRTOTIME($currentNumber));
        $theRange = $date . ",";
        $x++;
    }
    return $theRange;
}
```

Current result:

```
echo dateRange(7); // outputs a single date "2014-08-02,"
```

I need to return a string of dates, however it only seems to be pulling the LAST date in the function.

Looking for something like: "2014-08-08,2014-08-07,2014-08-06,2014-08-05,2014-08-04,"

Comment: Given your loop, you keep reassigning and overwriting previous values which were stored in your `$theRange` value. What would be required to keep adding onto the existing value until the loop is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by changing this line:

```
$theRange = $date . ",";
```

To use `.=` instead of `=`:

```
$theRange .= $date . ",";
```

The current code is overwriting the value of `$theRange` instead of appending to it.

---

**EDIT:** You could also use an array:

```
function dateRange($numberOfDays){
    $dates = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfDays, $i++) {
        $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-" . $i . " days"));
    }

    // Join the array elements together, separated by commas
    // Also add an extra comma on the end, per the desired output
    return implode(',', $dates) . ',';
}
```

Comment: It also needs a line to declare $theRange initially, otherwise the first time it tries to append there is nothing to append to

Comment: Awesome - THANK YOU! Should have just asked an hour ago!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you override the previous value of $theRange with each assignment, you need to use the string append operator ".=" and assign an initial value to $theRange, like below:

```
function dateRange($numberofDays){
    $theRange = "";    //added this line
    while($x<=$numberofDays) {
        $currentNumber = "-" . $x . " days";
        $date = DATE('Y-m-d', STRTOTIME($currentNumber));
        $theRange .= $date . ","; //changed this line
        $x++;
    }
    return $theRange;
}
```